# Is Klein gay? Is he gay for Kirito?

Tags: sword-art-online

At the end of episode 1, Klein tells Kirito that he looked cute, and was totally his type ([script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=sword-art-online-2012&episode=s01e01)):

> You were actually pretty cute.
>
> That's my type.

Does this mean something different in Japanese?  Was something lost in translation?  Or is Klein gay for Kirito?  Or is Klein gay in general?  I can't recall another anime that I've watched that had similar dialogue, but I don't watch anime where dudes are explicitly hot for each other either.

I'm re-watching SAO and I never noticed this the first two times through.

Answer (score 5):

I re-watched that episode because I also did not notice this. But it looks more like a friendly joke to me, given the events in that episode. If I remember correctly, Klein *does not show* any hints that he has romantic feelings to Kirito nor men in general throughout SAO.

**Why was I able to say it was a friendly joke?** Klein probably meant it as a joke that Kirito's face looks like a girl's that's his type. Also, as stated [here](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Tsuboi_Ryoutarou#Personality), 'Klein is also a "bachelor" and is shown trying to get together with various women in the series, such as Asuna, Freyja, and even Kazuto's sister, whom he had yet to meet.' If he was gay, he would be going after men or would have at least an episode or two to discuss his backstory as to why he felt that way.

Comment: I think Klein's attempt to try and get a girlfriend is the best counter for him being gay. I re-watched the first episode SAO on Netflix and it seems something is definitely lost in translation. The English *dialog* says "You look better this way" whereas the English *subtitles* says "You look cuter this way"

Answer (score 0):

Klein is definitely straight or at least bi, given that he fell for Freyja (ref: Calibur arc) and other girls.

My best guess is that Kirito's fairly delicate and 'definitely shows no sign of masculinity' looks would make Klein (initially and at first glance) mistake him as a girl. In addition, he entered the game at the age of 14, an age (at least in Japan) when youthfulness still persist.

Comment: Please include the references/sources you used. State the volume name, chapter, episode number, articles, etc. that you used.

Answer (score -1):

yeah he meant it as a friendly banter, I know loads of straight guys who joke around like that especially with younger or more fem guys, most gay men I know don't because its more real for them when they say it. and most gay men are into men not boys it kind of defeats the idea of being gay, and it be a very short relationship.. ends at 18 lol?

Comment: Hi amaru, welcome to the site. Try to answer the question using references or sources from the anime/manga. Otherwise the answer is really only an opinion.